# how can I add error classes to twitter bootstrap control group with multiple inputs ( not just 1 )

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a form which i am trying to validate using the plugin validate at  jquery.validate.js.

you can see it at you can see the live page at:

http://optionhomes.net/index.php/test1/index

The form is loaded from a database. I want the form to have the bootstrap error class added to class 'control group' if a validation error occurs. According to my understanding of the bootstrap documentation, that is how to do it.

I have HTML like so:

```
<div class="form_row" >

<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input01">city</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge span3" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->property->city ?>"  rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your city." data-original-title="city" >
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge span3" id="state" name="state" value="<?php echo $this->property->state ?>"  rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your state." data-original-title="state" >
            <input type="number" class="input-xlarge span2" id="zip" name="zip" value="<?php echo $this->property->zip ?>"  rel="popover" data-content="Re-enter your zip code." data-original-title="zip" >

          </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The jquery code is:

```
                errorClass: "error",
                errorElement: "span",
                highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                    $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');

                }
```

What I want to do is add the error class ( giving the red box ) to the input elements that fail validation. with my current code '.succes's classes are being added, turning these elements green , even when they need to be corrected.

The problem as I understand it is that with the multiple inputs if the last 1 scanned by jquery passes validation a '.sucess class' ( green outline ) is added. I want the control group to have the red .error class assigned if just 1 of the 3 inputs fails validation, no matter what the order

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: To which object, `errorClass` property belongs? is that a variable or a property?

Comment: Raminson, I am new to JS and Jquery. I think its a variable that is set and passed to the highlight function. Please see http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate